# My new database stop adding new documents when reach 25000

Tags: python, mongodb

I was creating a DB from a flat file with millions of data, using pymongo. Everything was running perfectly until the database reached 25000 documents. Now, my script is waiting (I don't know why) and my database is not growing more. This is the first time I use MongoDB (I'm already a newbie in NoSQL databases). It's very curious that DB growing stopped just in a rounded number (25000), it's like a limitation or something, maybe some miss-configuration on MongoDB (I'm using free version), but I couldn't find any information about this problem. Any suggestion?

I'm using Python 3.7.2, PyMongo 3.9.0, MongoDB 4.2.0 Community Edition and MongoDB Compass Community 1.19.6

My Python script (example of code):

```
class Save2DB:
    def __init__(self):
        self.connect()

    def connect(self):
        self.collection = pymongo.MongoClient()[db_name][collection_name]

    def write(self, info):
        self.coll_id = self.collection.insert_one(info.__dict__).inserted_id


class User:
    def __init__(self, line):
        self.name = line[10:125].strip()
        self.address = line[125:225].strip()
        self.phone = line[225:234].strip()
        self.email = line[234:275].strip()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print('\nFile: ' + fileName)
    fr = open(dirPath + os.sep + fileName, 'r', encoding='mbcs')
    lines = 0
    for line in fr:
        lines += 1
        line.strip()
        user = User(line)
        db = Save2DB()
        savedId = db.write(user)
        if lines % 1000 == 0:
            print('Users: ' + str(lines), end='\r')
    print()
```

Comment: Please provide more info about `DB version`, for example is it `community` or `atlas`?
As for me, I am using `community` version (that is free) with `node.js` (so it's js, not python) and even when I import data from extended file I don't have any limitations. No matter, during `-import stage` or in database/collection itself.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Alex. I already updated my question with version information. I'm using Python because it's faster to obtain and process data from a text file, but I'm working on a Node API to interact with the DB

Comment: Btw, I have noticed that you are using `Compass` so why don't you import your file via `Collection->Import Data`? I don't use PyMongo for importing data, but I choose `mongoimport` (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoimport). So I don't have relevant experience in your certain case, but the first thing what I was thinking about was: probably `_id` field (especially if you importing it) wasn't accepted by `DB` or not `unique`

Comment: The second thing, I also have problems with `mongoimport` tool and know couple of people that also have issuies too. In the end, I decide to import data from large files (*.csv 144k+ docs in my case) via `fs` module from `node.js` directly.

Comment: The only probable solution that I could see in your case, is to split file, into small ones and import them `one-by-one`. If it's really that big, just made two files by 15k docs each, for first 30k docs and try to import them. If the will be accepted, then 99% sure the solution of the problem wasn't within the `limitations` field

Comment: I can't use any automated import tool because relevant data is in one line (with a predefined format) and I need to split it in fields to create each document from each line.

Comment: Thanks Alex, for your time. I just find the problem. It wasn't in MongoDB or Python. It was on Windows shell. I'm confident with Linux, all my life I worked on Linux, but on my new job, I'm forced to use Windows (I really hate Windows). I clicked (without knowing of results) on the shell that is running the script and it stopped. I just press 'Esc' and it resume. Now it is running again. I learned another reason to hate Windows

Comment: Oh, I'm glad that you solved it. But actually, I know the solution for this case: try to use `new Windows Terminal` (https://github.com/microsoft/terminal) (also it could be downloaded from MS Store and supports `bash` commands, after some tweaks) or `Cmdler` (https://cmder.net/) One of this could help you to evade such problems in forceable future